SOQL Query Error question
I am writing this post because I am having trouble creating a soql query.
I want to find the values ​​of InspectionResult__c using the id of Stock__c.
But the query below fails. Please help. Is there a way?
error : the inner select field cannot have more than one level of relationships
select Id
from InspectionResult__c
where Inspection__r.GradeNew__c  IN
(
select Product__r.Grade__c
from Stock__c 
where id ='a2O0w000000TaxuEAC'
)



that is salesforce limitation. If you are in apex you might need to use 2 different queries first on Stock__c to get all the gradeIDs and then use that to query  InspectionResult__c.

The error you're encountering is due to the limitation in SOQL where the inner select field cannot have more than one level of relationships.
To work around this, you can break down the query into two separate queries and use a collection to store the intermediate results.
In the first query retrieve the Grade__c values from the Stock__c object and In the second query, Use the retrieved Grade__c values to query the InspectionResult__c object.
First Query:
List<Stock__c> stockList = [SELECT Product__r.Grade__c FROM Stock__c WHERE Id = 'a2O0w000000TaxuEAC'];
Set<String> gradeSet = new Set<String>();
for (Stock__c stock : stockList) {
        gradeSet.add(stock.Product__r.Grade__c);
}

Second Query:
List<InspectionResult__c> inspectionResults = [SELECT Id FROM InspectionResult__c WHERE Inspection__r.GradeNew__c IN :gradeSet];

